# ffmpeg generate libs only

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm trying to build ffmpeg static libraries to be used in VC++.
From a fedora machine I'm able to build ffmpeg successfully using the following configure option.

```
/configure --pkg-config=mingw32-pkg-config --prefix=$INSTALL_ROOT --disable-static --enable-memalign-hack --arch=x86 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32- --enable-shared
```

After generating the dlls, I've tried using `lib.exe` tool to generate libs.

```
lib /machine:i386 /def:avcodec-56.def /out:avcodec.lib
```

I'm getting lib files but the size of lib file is too small which indicates that I need dll also during the runtime. But what I need is single lib file which can be statically linked to one of my VC++ project and that project dll is only required. So my question is how to generate lib files only? (not lib and dll)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have set `--disable-static` in configure cmd line while you want a static lib?

Comment: @halfelf: If I enable-static, I'll get `.a` files only; but what I want actually is `.lib` files only for linking in visual studio.

Comment: MinGW generated `.a` libs are compatible with VC most of the time. You need to add them to linker input in visual studio. However, if you really want to make sure the binary compatibility, it's better to compile ffmpeg with msvc.

Comment: Also, I have same issue. I cloned project [link](https://github.com/ShiftMediaProject/FFmpeg/). I created successfully project on MSVC 2017.It create only lib but not creating **dll**. Please help me to generate **dll**